# Password expiration login.defs

Tags: passwords, redhat, user-accounts

As i was trying to set password policies for users on some of my servers (RedHat5), i was wondering if the settings in the /etc/login.defs file, and specifically those that specify password expiration, etc, apply also to the root account? For example, would the below also have an effect on root's  password?

```
PASS_MAX_DAYS   90
PASS_MIN_DAYS   7
PASS_MIN_LEN    5
PASS_WARN_AGE   14
```

I'm looking that the above settings don't affect root's password or the existing accounts that come with the OS, but only the accounts that created manually later.

It sounds like a silly question, but it hit me the other day and i had never really thought about it. It doesn't make sense that it would affect root's  password, but just wanted to have some more opinions on this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The stuff in /etc/login.defs only applies whenever you add new users or run the passwd command.  It won't impact your current accounts but if you run passwd as root it will enforce the requirements.  You can use the chage command (for example `chage -l root`) to view the settings for each user account.  It also appears in the fields in /etc/shadow.